# How to - Burn a cd(s) using cdfs?

Tags: windows-7

My Grandmother has a cd player in her home which only reads cds with the cdfs (Compact Disc File System). And my Grandfather likes to make backup copies of all their audio cds, just so the original doesn't get ruined. Although, he can't find a way to burn a cd using the cdfs, on his computer, it only allows udfs (Universal Data File System).

So I'm wondering how to burn a cd with the cdfs format. If anyone knows how, hopefully without use of excess burning software, please tell me how. Btw, he is running Windows 7. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm confused if you want an audio CD or a data CD containing audio files (for example, MP3s or WMAs). What's the brand name and model number of your grandmother's CD player? We might be able to find out more about what it can play and offer advice on what to burn.

Comment: Backing this one

CD-Audio is audio tracks playable by any CD audio player
CDFS is windows name for ISO9660 filesystem where you need to guess what ISO9660 extensions (like long filenames, or no filenames with spaces, or 2 levels of directory tree etc) the player does not support. 

About any CD recording program would create either format. Old players will reject -RW medium, and most players (as opposed to recorders) will require disk to be finalized before playing (~5s of writing lead-out blank.

Answer (score 1):

you need to burn the CD in "Joliet" File System.  When you burn the CD in "Joliet", the CD will show up as CDFS under properties.  For example, if you are using CD Creator, go to FILE / Project Properties.  Under File System, select Joliet.  Burn your media and the file system will be CDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Media Player can burn audio CDs.

Go to the Burn tab and drag music to the pane on the right.
[In the Burn Options menu, choose Audio CD](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Burn-a-CD-or-DVD-in-Windows-Media-Player).

Comment: Well yes of course, but the cd must be in the udfs format.

Comment: Wrong; WMP can burn audio CDs. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Burn-a-CD-or-DVD-in-Windows-Media-Player

Comment: Opps sorry, I meant to say that the cd player can only read cds in the cdfs.

Comment: This **is** CDFS.

Comment: Actually, an [audio CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Book_(CD_standard)) is not [CDFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660). I'm confused if James Litewski wants an audio CD or a data CD containing audio files (for example, MP3s or WMAs).

Answer (score 0):

[burrn](http://www.burrrn.net/?page_id=4) would do the trick for any windows version - its not native but really simple and does what its supposed to do. Just pull in the songs into the burrrn interface, get them in order and hit the button. Handles most of the common formats - wav, mp3, mpc, ogg, aac, mp4, ape, flac, ofr, wv and tta (I don't even know what tta is!), and is simple enough for a grandmother (or grandfather) to use.

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Mind expanding on this a bit?

Answer (score -1):

NERO : good for this.
download Nero -portable: https://yadi.sk/d/Kig3DR4x3LmbFX

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.